# How to transform a map to map in Terraform

Tags: functional-programming, terraform

I have a map in Terraform, values of which I want to transform by prepending them with a string, resulting in another map.

```
variable "my_map" {
  type = map(string)
}


locals {
  my_new_map = [for key, value in var.my_map: { key = "prefix/${value}"}]
}
```

But local.my_new_map is a tuple instead of a map. What am I missing for the result to be a map?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use the `map` syntax with `{` and `}` :

```
variable "my_map" {
  type = map(string)
}


locals {
  my_new_map = {for key, value in var.my_map: key => "prefix/${value}"}
}
```